# uninstalled npm still node-red is running in ubuntu16.04ls

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm, node-red

I have completely removed nodejs and npm but the package which i had installed using npm i.e. node-red  is running when I am typing "*node-red* " in terminal  in ubuntu 16.04ls
 I had installed nodejs and and npm  using "`apt-get install nodejs npm`"
and then I installed node-red using `npm install  node-red -g`

for uninstalling I did `apt-get unistall npm  nodejs` it get uninstalled successfully but now  when I am typing uninstalling node-red it is running

Comment: try to remove global node-red, `npm uninstall -g node-red`

Comment: tried doing it   still problem is remains same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that *node-red* file was stored in

> /use/local/bin/node-red

and it was running when I was typing node-red in Terminal. Also, there was one more file *node-red-pi* which I have removed now.
And this node-red is no more running now. which I wanted to do thanx @hmnzr and King Reload

Comment: No problem :) glad you were able to resolve your problem through our help!

Comment: Please accept your own answer :P so people can see it's been resolved ;)

Answer (score 0):

if @hmnzr doesn't work and `node-red` is a module from `npm` you could also use `npm remove -g node-red`,  then again if you just want to disable the module you could also use `disable`.

As another addition you could also not uninstall a module that is in use. That means to clear all Nodes of the plugin concerned before you uninstall it. Some you might need to delete manually though.

Further commands: `npm uninstall node-red-dashboard`

If you need to remove modules from Palette manager: click on `manage palette` and then click on `remove` to remove the module. However here as well you could `disable all`.